# Django Channels Channels-redis How can I access the database of redis and how can I use it?

Tags: django, redis, django-channels, channel

I used Django Channels for the first time and Redis for the first time through Channels.
I want to use the data stored in the redis server currently in use by django or save it in the redis server.

1. When listing chat rooms, I want to use channels_layer.receive_count to show the number of people who are accessing the chat room. (Like Twitch)
2. When I access the chat room, I want to list the information of the users there.

It would be nice if you could tell me how. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `channels_layer.receive_count` maps exactly to the number of active users. Here is an alternative.

You can use Django's session middleware to give each user a unique session_key. Then, use this to create an active_users list.

```
class RoomsConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    active_users = {}

    async def connect(self):
        self.room_id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_id']
        self.room_group_name = 'room_%s' % self.room_id

        # Add user to room count
        session_key = self.scope['session'].session_key
        if self.room_id not in self.active_users:
            self.active_users[self.room_id] = [session_key]
        elif session_key not in self.active_users[self.room_id]:
            self.active_users[self.room_id].append(session_key)
        # ...

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Remove user from room count
        session_key = self.scope['session'].session_key
        if self.room_id in self.active_users and \
           session_key in self.active_users[self.room_id]:
            # Remove my session key from the list
            self.active_users[self.room_id] = list(filter(
                lambda x: x != session_key,
                self.active_users[self.room_id]))
```

See:
https://github.com/ccnmtl/mathplayground/pull/270/files

`user_count = len(self.active_users[room_id])` will then be the number of active users in the given room.

In your django view, you will want to make sure each user actually has a session: https://github.com/ccnmtl/mathplayground/blob/main/mathplayground/rooms/views.py#L9